# When to use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() in webapplications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi can someone tell me when to use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`
in web application .Please provide me some real life example. Please do not mark it as duplicate question(My question is when to use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() and, not for loading properties file) . I have gone through many sites but I did not get proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please note that this method is not something `Java EE` related, it is a method of `Java SE` so it is not something that is meant to be used in web applications only but potentially in any Java applications.

We generally use this method with `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader)` in order to check and/or change the context `ClassLoader` of the calling thread.

So typically let's say that you are writing a Java Application that will need a custom `ClassLoader` that loads classes from specific folders and/or jar files that where not initially on the classpath, you would use these methods to change of context `ClassLoader` and restore the previous CL. This will allow your code to access to classes that where not accessible previously from the current context CL as they were not on the classpath initially.

So here is how your code would look like:

```
// The previous context ClassLoader
final ClassLoader contextCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    // Set my custom ClassLoader to make my classes accessible
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myCustomCL);
    // Execute some code here that will be able to access to classes or resources from
    // my specific folders and/or jar files

} finally {
    // Restore the previous CL
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextCL);
}
```

Comment: Tomcat uses this to set the WebApplicationClassloader. So, it is used in web applications I believe.